# C# textbox problem, how to cut the value of the textbox

Tags: c#, windows, forms

Hi i am writing an app in c# using windows form,
In this form i have a text box that get input form a user, And then I need to to some changes on it.
The problem is that the value in the text box is a long string with "\r\n" as a separator between lines.
How can I get the text in the text box, I need that every line will be a cell a so I can get a string[].

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`.Lines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx) property of TextBox control, that already contains the text splitted in lines.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
string temp = textBox1.Text;
string[] strList = temp.Split("\\r\\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using method Split("\r\n")  on the string returned from Textbox.Text